# R: apply functions and/or regress over across all the pairs of columns within groups (defined by time)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

The dataset looks like this
First column is time (year-month)
All the other columns are numeric values for firm a, firm b, firm c, etc.
Below is a fake data

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(time = c(1,1,2,2), a = c(1,2,3,4), b =c(4,3,2,1), c = c(1,1,1,1))
```

The operation needs to apply function and/or run regressions over each pair of the column a, b, c within each group of time
The expected output would look like this after applying an arbitrary function (sum over two columns)

```
expected_output <- tibble(t = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
firm1 = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"),
firm2 = c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
value = c(6,10,5,10,14,9,5,9,4,14,10,9,10,6,5,9,5,4))
expected_output
```

The function could be an arbitrary function with two inputs (column pairs of firm a, firm b, firm c, etc)

```
fun1<-function(x, y){
  sum(x, y)
}
```

My current method using tidyverse is as following, thanks to @akrun and @Ronak Shah

create all the pairs of firm a, b, c

```
tmp <- expand.grid(firm1 = names(data[-1]), firm2 = names(data[-1]))

result1 <- data %>%
group_split(time) %>%
map_df(~cbind(time = .x$time[1], tmp, value = apply(tmp, 1, function(x) fun1(.x[[x[1]]],.x[[x[2]]]))))
result1
```

The problem is, using real data, the above code is running so slow.
I guess the reason is 'map_df'. But I am new to such data analysis.
The real data has over 2,000 columns, which brings over 4 million pairs of columns.
Since data.table is famous in its efficiency and precision.
I am wondering if there is a way in data.table to accomplish such operations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this whether it is faster, even without using data.table.
It needs some time to create the data frame in the correct shape but then there is no need to use map or apply later on.

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(time = c(1,1,2,2), a = c(1,2,3,4), b =c(4,3,2,1), c = c(1,1,1,1))
data
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>    time     a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     4     1
#> 2     1     2     3     1
#> 3     2     3     2     1
#> 4     2     4     1     1
fun1<-function(x, y){
  sum(x, y)
}

data_agg = data %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols = a:c, .fns = sum))
data_agg
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>    time     a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     7     2
#> 2     2     7     3     2

data_agg_long <- data_agg %>% 
  pivot_longer(a:c)
data_agg_long
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>    time name  value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 a         3
#> 2     1 b         7
#> 3     1 c         2
#> 4     2 a         7
#> 5     2 b         3
#> 6     2 c         2

data_agg_long %>% 
  full_join(data_agg_long,
            by = "time") %>% 
  # might not be necessary if the function is vectorised
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(value = fun1(value.x, value.y)) %>% 
  select(time, firm1 = name.x, firm2 = name.y, value)
#> # A tibble: 18 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     time firm1 firm2 value
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     1 a     a         6
#>  2     1 a     b        10
#>  3     1 a     c         5
#>  4     1 b     a        10
#>  5     1 b     b        14
#>  6     1 b     c         9
#>  7     1 c     a         5
#>  8     1 c     b         9
#>  9     1 c     c         4
#> 10     2 a     a        14
#> 11     2 a     b        10
#> 12     2 a     c         9
#> 13     2 b     a        10
#> 14     2 b     b         6
#> 15     2 b     c         5
#> 16     2 c     a         9
#> 17     2 c     b         5
#> 18     2 c     c         4
```